# Dipolar moment in a volume differential

Tags: electrostatics

Imagine there is a volume of a neutral dielectric. An electric field has been applied so the it is polarized. The definition is its net dipolar moment is

$ \vec{p}^{\,}= \int \rho \vec{r}^{\,} dv $

therefore, the $ \vec{dp}^{\,} = \rho \vec{r}^{\,} dv $ that means dp is parallel to the vector position of dv.

However. While trying to calculate the potencial of a all the volume, books replace the dipolar moment of two charges $ \vec{p}^{\,}$ by $\vec{dp}^{\,}$ but their orientations are nothing similar according to the first equation.

I think that even in a dv there's a net dipolar moment, which can be thought as a dipole, but the first definition causes me trouble. Thanks.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density